# javascript - use variables of input and form names to reference input element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I have a two variables. One containing the value of the `name` attribute of an input element, and another containing the value of the name attribute of its form element.

Using JavaScript how do I reference that input element just like below, except for replacing the inputname with the value of the variable that contains the name attribute of the input element, and the formname with the value of the variable that contains the name attribute of the form element?

```
document.formname.inputname
```

---

I don't mean to sound complicated, and I am looking forward to a reply,

-An inquisitive Web Developer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I think you could just use this:

```
document.forms['nameOfForm']['nameOfFormElement'];
```

And to get the value of the elements, just append `.value` to the end:

```
document.forms['nameOfForm']['nameOfFormElement'].value;
```

Comment: You could of course jump straight to the form element with `document.getElementsByName('nameOfFormElement')[0].value`.

Comment: Notice that `getElementsByName` has an `s` in it, which makes it plural, so it's an array. You'd have to do `document.getElementsByName('nameOfFormElement')[0].value` to make it work properly, as `name` isn't unique.

Comment: Good catch @Blender. I know how to use the function but apparently I don't know how to proof-read my comments before I submit them. :)

Comment: Before I began using jQuery, you have no idea how many times' I've made this mistake with `document.getElementsByClassName`. It took me a while to find that `s`!

Comment: I can definitely empathize with the headache of searching for a string when you've returned an array. Actually, my most notorious trip-up along these lines is attempting to use objects like arrays.